# Paperclip separate styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How can i separate styles for different models?

I have my `Photo model` which generate my styles

`large:'300x300#',huge:'800x800'`

also i have two models witch use this styles

`Product`

and

`Post`

so i want to use

`large style` only for `Product`

and `huge style` only for `Post`

```
product => has_many :photos

post => has_one :photo

photo => belongs_to :post
      belongs_to :product
has_attached_file :image, :styles => {large:'300x300#',huge:'800x800'}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: provide model's code please

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ updated

Comment: where is the code mounting paperclip?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to separte image by a image model type using STI, and polymorphism, therefore, add `imageable_type`, `imageable_id`, and `type` field to photo model, so:

**app/models/photo.rb**:

```
class Photo < AR::Base
   belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**app/models/photos/large_photo.rb**:

```
class LargePhoto < Photo
   has_attached_file :image, :styles => { large:'300x300#' }
end
```

**app/models/photos/huge_photo.rb**:

```
class HugePhoto < Photo
   has_attached_file :image, :styles => { huge:'800x800' }
end
```

**app/models/product.rb**:

```
class Product < AR::Base
   has_many :large_photos, as: imageable
end
```

**app/models/post.rb**:

```
class Post < AR::Base
   has_one :huge_photo, as: imageable
end
```

**BUT** for me, will be better to use `carrierwave`, rather than `paperclip` for this case.